# java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: java, jsf

im doing j2ee with primefaces and web 2.0
and currently stuck here with this error

```
    java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement40
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.doWriteState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:293)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.writeState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:167)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:123)
com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:155)
com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:221)
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:397)
com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
```

some googling says that i need to implements Serializable all class that i used in this function.but i've already done that.and this error seems quite general,i cant quite figure this out.and dont really understand error below

```
    org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement40
```

Comment: Does the class you are trying to serialize have a non-transient PreparedStatement member variable?

Comment: yup.i supposed to declare PrepareStatement as transient right?
seems everything okay now
problem solved.thanks

Comment: It's an extremely bad idea to get hold of a `PreparedStatement` (or `Connection` or `ResultSet` as an instance variable. Your problem is bigger than alone this exception. The normal JDBC idiom mandates that the DB resources like `Connection`, `Statement` and `ResultSet` should be opened and closed in the **shortest possible scope**. I.e. in the very same method block as where you're using them.

Comment: I agree with BalusC - it's generally a strange decision to hold PreparedStatements as member variables. It's much more common to create, use and dispose of them within a single method call.

Comment: @BalusC: I was also doing a similar mistake & your comment just saved me. *Many Thanks!*. I was trying to hold `ResultSet` of a DB(cassandra) query in the viewMap & same problem arose. Btw what is bad thing about this ? Should the `ResultSet` data be instead copied to self made instance variables(for my case a hashmap) and then put in JSF viewMap ? *(I need this data to manage user's actions on a webpage while user posts back from the same view.)*

Comment: @Marcos: it's bad because you're unnecessarily keeping DB resources open and leaking them away. Just map the resultset to a collection of beans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're storing a (JDBC) PreparedStatement in one of your objects that is getting serialized (probably part of a session). You should move it somewhere else or mark it transient (don't forget it will be missing when it gets restored).

Comment: i should make the preparestatement as transient. didnt know about transient before.
and i did move it somewhere else too.
both solution works just fine.
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the object you are trying to serialize has a reference to org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement40, or most probably, to a java.sql.Statement, which is the interface that class implements.
You have to remove that reference to make it work

Answer (score 0):

The clue is here:

```
StateManagerImpl.writeState
```

It is likely that you have set an inappropriate value on one of your components. You probably need to use EL binding in a place where you have explicitly called `setValue` in a backing bean (my best guess based on the information posted).

JSF uses stateful UI component trees that are persisted between requests. The tree structure and any value set on the tree is saved at the end of the Render Response phase. Typically, data is saved either in the session or in a hidden form field. Therefore, any value set on a component must be serializable.